# s.indexOf is not a function at Function.n.fromString

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, material-ui

I have no idea why I'm getting this error or from where is coming from because I think I'm not using that ?

I'm doing a firebase update after an user update a row from DataGrid MUI and I'm doing the update as I would normally do nothing different at all and it just jumps into that error.

I'm not sure if is an React error, JS error, Firebase error, MUI error. but I THINK is a firebase error because the path says so

[image]

[image]

This is what I was trying to do:

```
const [editRowsModel, setEditRowsModel] = React.useState({});
const [editRowData, setEditRowData] = React.useState({});

const handleEditRowsModelChange = React.useCallback(
  (model) => {
    const editedIds = Object.keys(model);

    if (editedIds.length === 0) {
      
      console.log(editRowData)
      console.log(editRowData.uid)
      console.log(editRowData.nombre)
      console.log(editRowData.colegio)
      console.log(editRowData.grado)
      
      const temporalQuery = db.collection("usuarios").doc(user.uid).collection("estudiantes").doc(editRowData.uid);
              temporalQuery.update({
                nombre: editRowData.nombre,
                colegio: editRowData.colegio,
                grado: editRowData.grado
              })
    } else {
      setEditRowData(model[editedIds[0]]);
    }
    setEditRowsModel(model);
  },
  [editRowData]
);
```

This is what the `console.log` shows up. I honestly don't see any error in the way I code it that's how I always do it, never had an issue before. First time I update from a nested collection though

[image]

This is how it looks in the firebase

[image]

And yes the `user.uid` also comes correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue is because the data comes with a whole string of information instead of just the value as I though it was coming.

All I had to do was to call the field + the value when I was using it.
Ej:

if I wanted the uid I had to call it editRowData.uid.value

Answer (score 0):

the `.doc(name)` only accepts strings, so check if your `user.uid` is a string